# How do I empty the buffer inside the loop each iteration in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a for loop to fill an array. This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Student " + (i+1));

        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        students[i][0] = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        students[i][1] = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
        students[i][2] = keyboard.nextLine();

    }
```

however when I run it outputs the following:

> First Name: Last Name:

and will read only one string for the First Name and Last Name.

This only happens on the first iteration, the following iterations are all fine. I think this might have something to do with emptying the buffer but why does it only happen the first time?

Comment: we can't help if we don't know what the `keyboard` variable is. Can you post where that is initialized?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you have an end of line character that wasn't dealt with properly before this block of code is called.  Do you use any of Scanner's other methods such as nextInt(), nextDouble(), or next()?  If so, then you may need to follow these method calls with a call to nextLine() to swallow the end of line token.  For e.g.

```
int myInt = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();  // call this to swallow end of line character

double myDouble = keyboard.nextDouble();
keyboard.nextLine();
```